# How to get exact number of working days and hours between two dates using MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have to find the number of working days between two dates where I need to exculde some days between those dates(Ex: every thursday,Wendesday But these days are dynamic which can be changed by user)

I attached the sample code below

```
SELECT CONCAT (
FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-12-09 17:13:00', '2017-01-01 17:34:00')/(24*60*60)) -
((WEEK('2015-01-01 17:07:00') - WEEK('2014-12-30 21:59:00')) * 2) -
(case when weekday('2017-01-01 17:34:00') = 6 then 1 else 0 end) -
(case when weekday('2016-12-09 21:59:00') = 5 then 1 else 0 end), 'Days ',

TIME_FORMAT(
SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DATE_FORMAT('2016-12-09 21:59:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT('2017-01-01 17:34:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) -(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,DATE_FORMAT('2016-12-09 21:59:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT('2017-01-01 17:34:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'))/(24*60*60))*24*60*60))), '%H:%i'), 'Hrs'
)
```

But I am getting issue in Week Difference((WEEK('2015-01-01 17:07:00') - WEEK('2014-12-30 21:59:00')) * 2), I have also tried ROUND(DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date)/7, 0) in place of Week Difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the below query, if 2 non-working days are excluded 5-saturday, 6-sunday.**

```
SELECT created_at, updated_at, IF(
(YEAR(created_at)=YEAR(updated_at)), 
CONCAT (FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, updated_at)/(24*60*60)) -
    ((WEEK(updated_at) - WEEK(created_at)) * 2) -
    (case when weekday(updated_at) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) -
    (case when weekday(created_at) = 5 then 1 else 0 end), 'Days ',

    TIME_FORMAT(
        SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) -(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'))/(24*60*60))*24*60*60))), '%H:%i'), 'Hrs'
), 

CONCAT (
    FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, updated_at)/(24*60*60)) -
    (((((YEAR(updated_at)-YEAR(created_at))*52)+WEEK(updated_at)) - WEEK(created_at)) * 2) -
    (case when weekday(updated_at) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) -
    (case when weekday(created_at) = 5 then 1 else 0 end), 'Days ', 
    TIME_FORMAT(
        SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) -(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'))/(24*60*60))*24*60*60))), '%H:%i'), 'Hrs'
)
)
FROM Test_table
```